# Filling a shell script array with data

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, shell

I want to extract some data from a file and save it in an array, but i don't know how to do it.

In the following I'm extracting some data from /etc/group and save it in another file, after that I print every single item:

```
awk -F: '/^'$GROUP'/ { gsub(/,/,"\n",$4) ; print $4 }' /etc/group > $FILE

for i in `awk '{ print $0 }' $FILE`
   do
     echo "member: "$i" "
   done
```

However, I don't want to extract the data into a file, but into an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
members=( $(awk -F: '/^'$GROUP':/ { gsub(/,/,"\n",$4) ; print $4 }' /etc/group) )
```

The assignment with the parentheses indicates that `$members` is an array.  The original `awk` command has been enclosed in `$(...)`, and the colon added so that if you have `group` and `group1` in the file, and you look for `group`, you don't get the data for `group1` too.  Of course, if you wanted both entries, then you drop the colon I added.

Answer (score 2):

```
j=0
for i in `awk '{ print $0 }' $FILE`
do
  arr[$j] = $i
  j=`expr $j + 1`
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr=($(awk -F: -v g=$GROUP '$1 == g { gsub(/,/,"\n",$4) ; print $4 }' /etc/group))
```

Comment: +1 Exactly what I had. You should always quote your variables

Comment: @steve Not quite, you're comparing the wrong column to $GROUP.